# Como guardo/leo un vector que no se sabe le tamaño en un archivo binario c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11, c++17, c++98

estoy con un proyecto y tengo un problema para guardar datos.

```
struct registrar_venta{
    float reg_ticket;
    //registrar vector que no se el tamaño, pueden ser 5,6,8,10,20,30,50
    float reg_total;
    float reg_fecha;
};
```

Tengo un vector de struct donde **cada struct tiene dos datos, un *string* (para guardarlo usaria un char [10] ) y un *int*, pero no puedo saber si son 10 o 20**, guardarlos no es problema, el tema es leerlo luego, porque cada dato que guardo debo leerlo y no se si cuanto ocupa un "ticket" ya que todos varian segun la cantidad de productos vendidos.

Pense en hacerlo para archivo txt, donde puedo colocar un /end/ donde termina cada ronda de datos, pero no se que tan problematico sea, la idea era usar solo archivos binarios.
[image: imagen de muestra archivo TXT]

1. leo la primera línea = nro ticket.
2. leo segunda línea = total.
3. leo tercera línea = fecha.
4. leo de la cuarta línea para abajo CODIGO hasta que llegue al end y ahí corto, repito el bucle.

Pero no se como hacer esto así que si es lo que me recomiendan me pondría a investigar.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto que planteas es un problema habitual de [serialización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n) y tiene una sencilla solución: Para datos de longitud variable, primero guarda la longitud del dato y después su contenido.

En el siguiente ejemplo se guarda en archivo un objeto que tiene un nombre (`std::string`) de tamaño variable junto a una serie de datos numéricos (`std::vector`) también de tamaño variable:

```
struct Dato
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::vector<int> valores;
};
```

Se serializa sobrecargando el operador de escritura en archivo:

```
std::ofstream &operator <<(std::ofstream &o, const Dato &d)
{
    std::size_t longitud_nombre = d.nombre.size();
    std::size_t longitud_valores = d.valores.size();

    // Primero escribimos la longitud del nombre.
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&longitud_nombre), sizeof(longitud_nombre));
    // Despues el nombre.
    o.write(d.nombre.c_str(), longitud_nombre);
    // A continuacion la cantidad de valores.
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&longitud_valores), sizeof(longitud_valores));
    // Despues los valores.
    for (const auto &valor : d.valores)
        o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&valor), sizeof(valor));

    return o;
}
```

Y se deserializa sobrecargando el operador de lectura desde archivo:

```
std::ifstream &operator >>(std::ifstream &i, Dato &d)
{
    std::size_t longitud_nombre;
    std::size_t longitud_valores;

    // Primero leemos la longitud del nombre.
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&longitud_nombre), sizeof(longitud_nombre));
    d.nombre.clear();
    // Y luego todas las letras del nombre.
    for (int indice = 0; indice != longitud_nombre; ++indice)
    {
        char letra;
        i.read(&letra, 1);
        d.nombre.push_back(letra);
    }
    // Despues leemos la cantidad de valores.
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&longitud_valores), sizeof(longitud_valores));
    d.valores.clear();
    // Y a continuacion todos los valores.
    for (int indice = 0; indice != longitud_valores; ++indice)
    {
        int valor;
        i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&valor), sizeof(valor));
        d.valores.push_back(valor);
    }

    return i;
}
```

También he sobrecargado el operador de escritura en consola para que pueda ser usado así:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Dato &d)
{
    o << d.nombre << " = { ";
    for (const auto &valor : d.valores)
        o << valor << ' ';
    return o << '}';
}

int main()
{
    Dato fibonacci{"Fibonacci", {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21}};
    Dato pi{"pi", {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5}};

    std::cout << "Antes de escribir en archivo: " << fibonacci << '\n' << pi << '\n';

    if (std::ofstream fichero{"datos.txt", std::ios::binary})
        fichero << fibonacci << pi;

    Dato leido1, leido2;
    if (std::ifstream fichero{"datos.txt", std::ios::binary})
        fichero >> leido1 >> leido2;

    std::cout << "Despues de leer de archivo: " << leido1<< '\n' << leido2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTbjtowEH1OvmJKJQjdFC1sW7UJG6nSar@iEjKOA1aDHTkOvSC@nY7t3BqWluUlGc/1zJmxaVG8pzkRm9PpLRc0r1IGSy5LrRjZJX6ny85VqOFi09fsGdVSJb6PpopqeCJa@gffK3UaRc4dhNytFYtrpYtYcqET2JNcKlbG/jE2GdAq66owlgVTmEzBchkMTSFQKUpXDcbptKvIf7OVhlyKDddVunKl4RHSmRNnxiOYxhf8a0A2oJbbCN@Tsx@KaxYohuiZKhTTK0pKvXRo6JYoeJcE40H5aQgmh8yCocHgaJK2COkK@wwwaOgd34CgbuIFCI3FdpYhz4HLQSrDqbVC1NEw9b2rq9uQrqQ72joYUSkBEideD5yfDzxJgoGJh9eO@j@DNRj4DJOmLzRx0/i6seWMKLtZlkxMDlyknJrtu48b@c3jGWK4u3NGpBib8yyOnGlFMFeDdmwVIcxNga5oUZXb1ZrQ74G1G@PxVS1etR9edxle32XD/LBNE2ptvS4vA760Ul4PW0eGM9dk1DvHu52Tl9@Yfz4xEv3al8TII@z6AKP46gtkgpwFhQlM4u5KWM1xYlEabnaEi8CWtRAyvpaCUMoPo@dGHIVwmONOhLAI4SGEjyF8xiNKi/kRn1QXWWBIYX0frO8H@0XfLzbuE8rGub44VFbatvYVJ1ECvvGspIqvuQImgCi65XsZYefo02Ky2L@JifkX7cletgwGr3fG6ZYpeRilCK6c6Z8aobn7LssoWnNB1K@jYav2PKtUcJPZ9pYznkrsxv4Xca8ev71ektR5W2lxTs8TK4vKEZQzpsz/b3Jcih4xLlOfnHr09zjz0@kP)</kbd>.

Comment: Entendi el concepto! Muchisimas gracias, no voy a hacerlo tal cual pero la respuesta era muy sencilla, guardar cuanto mide cada ticket y tenerlo como valor. Es simple pero muy efectivo, vamos a ver como se da en la practica. Repito, muchisimas gracias.