# Leer archivo .dat en modo binario C++

Tags: c++

actualmente intento leer la información que contiene un archivo .dat que fue escrito en modo binario pero solo obtengo como resultado de consola formatos incorrectos, como podría arreglar el siguiente código?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    char a[2000];
    ifstream ficheroLeer("documentoejemplo.dat", ios::binary);

    ficheroLeer.read((char *) a, sizeof(a));

    for(int i=0; i<300; i++) {
        cout << a[i];
    }

    ficheroLeer.close();
}
```

La estructura del .dat es la siguiente:

```
struct Ciclista {
    int dorsal;
    cadena pais;
    cadena nombre;
    cadena apellidos;
    int marca;
    int posicion;
};
```

Comment: Y cual es el formato del `.dat`? Cuales son los "formatos incorrectos" que te salen en consola? Cuales son los correctos que esperarías que te salieran? Faltan muchos detalles para que podamos empezar a ayudarte con esta pregunta. Trata de publicar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ahí subí toda la información que tengo, en consola directamente no me sale nada, ya que lo estoy leyendo de alguna manera incorrecta.

Comment: Si lo escribiste en binario posiblemente tengas que pasar el archivo por algún proceso de decodificación. ¿Podrías decirnos cómo estás generando el archivo `.dat` para que podamos ayudarte mejor? Por cierto, los arreglos se convierten implícitamente en punteros. La conversión explícita no es necesitaria.

Comment: No lo escribí yo, fue dado directamente por un profesor en el enunciado, y claro no consigo leer el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Cómo podría arreglar el siguiente código?

No tiene arreglo, está todo mal: bórralo pues no sirve de nada.

---

No has entendido en qué consiste leer de un archivo en modo binario (la extensión del archivo es indiferente) ni qué es un archivo en modo binario.

Los flujos de datos (`stream`) asumen que se trabaja con texto, lo que implica que algunos caracteres serán tratados de manera especial<sup>1</sup> o que lo escrito en el archivo dependerá de la [codificación de caracteres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres), cuando tratas un archivo en modo binario no sucede nada de eso; en otras palabras: en modo binario del archivo se lee o escribe la información en crudo (tal y como está en el archivo).

Una vez aclarado eso, cuando ejecutas estas instrucciones:

```
char a[2000];
ifstream ficheroLeer("documentoejemplo.dat", ios::binary);
ficheroLeer.read((char *) a, sizeof(a));
```

Lo que haces es leer del archivo `"documentoejemplo.dat"` 1'9kbytes de datos en crudo y los almacenas en una formación de caracteres que acto seguido:

```
for(int i=0; i<300; i++) {
    cout << a[i];
}
```

Imprimes tal cual la has leído; lo cuál no tiene sentido pues sólo imprimirás bytes, no **interpretarás** lo que significan. Muy probablemente lo que quieres hacer es crear unas rutinas de [serialización y deserialización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n), te aconsejo consultar [este tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516971/como-guardo-leo-un-vector-que-no-se-sabe-le-tama%C3%B1o-en-un-archivo-binario-c) para averiguar cómo hacerlo.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Por ejemplo, los saltos de línea `\n` pueden ser transformados en salto de línea con [retorno de carro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retorno_de_carro) `\n\r`

Comment: De plano la única manera que se me ocurre para almacenar en binario algo es: `stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&variable), sizeof(variable))` y para leerlo `stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&variable), sizeof(variable))`. Pero como no sabemos de qué manera se está codificando el archivo no es fácil responder.

Comment: @Mateo ni el autor de la pregunta sabe cómo se codifica el archivo. Al menos ahora tiene información para saber qué debe hacer para averiguarlo.